# Python : How to see if all rows were printed?

Tags: python

I have a code which prints the rows which are in SQL database. What I need is to know if they were printed. For example what I have in my code is simple print, but I'm trying to do also add an `input("Enter anything to continue")`
And for it to work I somehow have to make the if statement? In my code I added `continue`, but that gives me error and I can't return to my menu when entering anything in input  function. If I would add these inputs to continue in `for rows in adminu_data:` They would not work how they should. For example when one row is printed the `time.sleep(5)` and other lines works.

```
 finally:
                    #closing database connection.
                    if(connection):
                        cursor.close()
                        connection.close()
                        print ("ID, NUMBER, APP-LAUNCH-TIME, REGISTERD-TIME")
                        for rows in adminu_data:
                            print ("Registered. ",rows)
                            time.sleep(5)
                            input("\n* Enter anything to continue... ")
                            os.system('cls')
                        input("Enter anything to return to main menu")
                        continue
```

EDIT **

For those who don't understand is what I'm trying to do is: When the lines were printed with `for rows in adminu_data:`, I need to make a simple `input("press enter to continue")`, but the problem is that the print function prints multiple lines, after printing one line this code would launch it I would add it  `input("press enter to continue")`. So what I need to do is after completed printing lines, launch the input code.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please explain again what is the desired behavior.

Comment: How to print `input("Enter anything to continue") ` and `continue` after the rows were printed

Comment: Also it would be usefull to have a code sample containing your problem to test with. Your snippet contains multiple things that have nothing to do with your error (also that might help you figure it out yourself)

Comment: Doesn't help. Imagine you're talking to a baby. Explain in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to wait for the user input after printing everything just delete the first input:

```
def main():
    adminu_data = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
        print ("ID, NUMBER, APP-LAUNCH-TIME, REGISTERD-TIME")
        for rows in adminu_data:
            print ("Registered. ",rows)
        input("Enter anything to continue")
```

You might want to provide a sample of your data if theres still something wrong.

Comment: I have a loop, this code is launched when database connection is closed.

Comment: This is a good answer to everybody, but I'll try to fix my problem myself.

Comment: I´ve updated my answer but i feel like your problem isnt really captured in the code snipped so not sure if this is what you are looking for